# Need help to resolve errors un using py2exe missing

Tags: import, installation, py2exe, missing-data

The following modules appear to be missing

- email.Generator
- email.Iterators
- email.Utils
- win32api
- win32con
- w in32pipe
- wx

**My setup file looks like this:**

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['fwsm_migration.py'])
```

**i'm using Python 2.5.4 and the py2exe 0.6.8**

Looked here and outside for a peculiar solution but have not found one!!

read about using "optoins: but being new to python itself failing to know where to do it.

Please HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/). After having a hell of a time with py2exe [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) compiled my script without any configuration. In the same environment Py2exe claimed I'd missed nine packages.

For simple scripts you only need to do:

```
cxfreeze hello.py --target-dir dist
```

Comment: Thanks!!But i'm using cmd prompt, so is the cx_Freeze available to be used from cmd prompt?

Comment: Yes, that command should be run from "cmd prompt" on Windows. it lives in c:\PythonXX\Scripts once installed.